# Initialize Facebook Utils

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I am trying to use the Parse login and sign up views. Specifically I am trying to log in using facebook with the parse login view.

Everything works fine except when i click the "login with facebook button" the app crashes. It gives me the following crash report

'You must initialize PFFacebookUtils with a call to +initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions'

I have searched everywhere and apparently I am meant to add in `[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];` However `initializeFacebook` gives me an error, I think its outdated.

Apparently with the new code I am meant to write this `[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions];` but it gives me an error when I try run the app saying 'You have to call setApplicationId:clientKey: on Parse to configure Parse.' which is weird because I have called setApplicationId?

Can anyone please help me out! It would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully these articles will help you come to a solution. I am developing the same and been running around a few places.

Issues with launch options
[PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions) giving compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727608/pffacebookutils-initializefacebookwithapplicationlaunchoptionslaunchoptions-gi)

Tutorial http://blog.oskoui-oskoui.com/?p=8161

Answer (score 0):

did you well called #import < ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h >
 the V4 ?