# PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions) giving compilation error

Tags: parse-platform, parsefacebookutils

I'm trying to integrate facebook login in my parse application. I followed every step mentioned in parse tutorial. In the below code, I'm getting compilation error.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    line1: Parse.setApplicationId("xxx", clientKey: "yyy")
    line2: PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)       
    line3: PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    line4: return true
}
```

In **line 3**, I'm getting error:

> Value of optional type '`[NSObject:AnyObject]`' not unwrapped; did you
>   mean to use '`!`' or '`?`'?

If I manually unwrap it using '`!`', because launchOptions can be nil, I get:

> Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

If I check for nil, I get:

> `NSInternalInconsistencyException`', reason: 'You must initialize
>   PFFacebookUtils with a call to
>   `+initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions`

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug in ParseSDK. Until Parse fix this you can change the initialize function declaration at PFFacebookUtils.h header file

1) Go to PFFacebookUtils.h

2) change:

- (void)initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;

To:

- (void)initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:(PF_NULLABLE NSDictionary *)launchOptions;

This answer was provided by Kiarash Akhlaghi at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1462780714012820/

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a bug of ParseSDK, it does not accept nil **launchOptions**

According to the the answer provided by Roger Ingouacka at
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1462780714012820/

```
    if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    } else {
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions([NSObject:AnyObject]())
    }
```

Notice the use of

`[NSObject:AnyObject]()`

Answer (score 0):

This problem persisted untill I **updated to Parse library 1.8.1**.

I tried adjusting PFFacebookUtils.h, and a lot of other things, but that did not solve it. It was driving me insane.