# "no known class method for selector" error for Facebook Parse integration in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I'm following Parses instructions for implementing FB login [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-setup).

I've followed all the steps up to step 5, but when I get to the part where I add these two lines of code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"parseAppId" clientKey:@"parseClientKey"];
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

I get an error stating:

> no known class method for selector initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:

I've imported everything I possibly can in the app delegate:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "DefaultSettingsViewController.h"
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import "Branch.h"
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727608/pffacebookutils-initializefacebookwithapplicationlaunchoptionslaunchoptions-gi

Comment: You've got two imports of `PFFacebookUtils.h`, from different frameworks. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ixx I tried that solution, didn't work.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah, I tried importing both because I wasn't sure which one had the headers needed. I've also tried commenting out one import and using the other, that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Did you add the ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework to your xcode project? Also, it looks like you're using v4 of the Facebook SDK, so make sure you only use ParseFacebookUtilsV4.