# Parse saveInBackgroundWithBlock crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nszombieenabled

I am adding some data into my parse class (table) successfully.

After saving is successfully completed (I can see the data on website), my app crashes without leaving any message on console. I tried to get a message by using "Enable Zombie Objects" setting. This is the message I am getting which has nothing to do what I am doing:

```
-[UIActivityIndicatorView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x126d16780
```

I do not have any `UIActivityIndicatorView` in my whole project.

This is how I save my data:

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!

        var userCase = PFObject(className: "Case")
        userCase.relationForKey("user").addObject(currentUser)
        userCase["caseCode"] = "test_code"
        userCase.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // The object has been saved.
                println("saved")
            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
                println("error occurred: \(error?.description)")
            }
        }
```

Swift SDK version: 1.7.5
Xcode version: 6.4

Has anybody have ever faced with such problem?

**UPDATE:** This error does not occur on simulator (tested on iPhone 5, iPhone 5S, iPhone 6) and does not occur on device at first run.

Tried removing and re-installing the app.

**UPDATE 2:** Removing `PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)` or changing it to `PFFacebookUtils.initialize()` from AppDelegate fixes the issue but I think I need to use `initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)`. I have another problem now.

Comment: Where is the line that crashes? Are you sure it's related to your saveInBackgroundWithBlock?

Comment: There is no line that it crashes. Xcode focuses AppDelegate.swift file on crash. It just crashes whenever I use Parse API. If I remove Parse codes, no crush occurs.

Comment: The first danger you have in your code is the first line: var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()! Replace that with "if var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() { // code }. PFUser.currentUser() can return a "nil", and you're forcing it to unwrap then you proceed to add a nil currentUser to your "user" relation,

Comment: It is just an example to see if saving works. I am totally sure currentUser is not null in this case.

Comment: Ok, if you say so. Can you println the "error" even if it's success, to see if there is actually an error? Usually, you can't pretend that because success is true that error is nil, but in this case it seems acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, error is nil. I just printed.

Comment: what is the problem you are having

Comment: whenever I use PFFacebookUtils with Facebook SDK together my app is crashing.

Comment: Try setting up an exception breakpoint to see where it really crashes. (Select Objective-C under Exceptions, even for Swift) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: A full stack trace would help too

Comment: @BojanDimovski no difference. I still get the "*** -[UIActivityIndicatorView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x154d0c8e0" error.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following.

```
1) Go to PFFacebookUtils.h

2) change:

(void)initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
To:

(void)initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:(PF_NULLABLE NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

It was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29756402/1220477)